# Python Dash Mapboxgl Polygon click event data,

Tags: plotly, mapbox-gl-js, plotly-dash

How to get the data (geojson properties - name, id etc) from the mapboxgl polygon click event in python dash/plotly?

Below is Dash Graph element

```
layer = dict(
        type="fill",
        below='traces',
        color="#18607e",
        opacity=0.7,
        hovermode="closest",
        interactive=True,
        text=[x['properties']['id'] for x in geojson['features']],
        source=geojson,
        sourcetype="geojson"

    )

    element = dcc.Graph(
                id='TxWCD-choropleth',
                figure=dict(
                    data=[dict(
                        type='scattermapbox'
                    )],
                    layout=dict(
                            plot_bgcolor="#18607e",
                            paper_bgcolor="#18607e",
                            clickmode="event+select",
                            mapbox=dict(
                                layers=[layer],
                                accesstoken=_token,
                                center=dict(
                                    lat=53.350140,
                                    lon=-6.266155
                                ),
                                zoom=1,
                                style='light'
                            ),
                            height=600,
                            autosize=True,
                            margin=dict(
                                l=0,
                                r=0,
                                b=0,
                                t=0,
                                pad=4
                            )
                    )
                )
            )
```

Call Back event:

```
app.callback(
    Output(component_id='graphs', component_property='children'),
    [Input('map-flex', "n_clicks")]
)
def update_graph(data):

    # Do some updates
    # Expected result: mapbox click event data geojson properties

    return ''
```

Expected Result:

On click of Mapbox polygon return Mapbox event data. i.e. geojson properties.

Any help or workaround is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Check out the documentation of the [scattermapbox](https://plotly.com/python/reference/#scattermapbox). There is an attribute called `customdata` which you can use to determine what is passed to your callback.

To define the callback you can use this [reference](https://dash.plotly.com/interactive-graphing). Essentially you are doing the following steps:

1. Add clickmode attribute to your graph layout:

   ```
   'layout': {
       'clickmode': 'event+select'
   }
   ```
2. Define your callback:

   ```
   @app.callback(
       Output(component_id='graphs', component_property='children'),
       [Input('map-flex', 'clickData')]) 
   def display_click_data(custom_data):
       print(custom_data)
   ```